# what happens when multiple queries need to access the same data from a datanode?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

When we fire multiple queries simultaneously and 2 queries need to access the same data. What happens in Map Reduce?

Suppose only  1 copy of the data is present in one node and 2 queries need to access data from the same data node. what happens? Will one of the query wait in a queue or is it processed simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

The queries will be processed simultaneously, when one queue comes a new thread will be started to handle it, you can see the source code [here](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u1/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/datanode/DataXceiverServer.java#126).

Comment: So, Its like every time 2 queries need to access the data from the same data node, there will not be a queue instead threads/ instances are created such that they can access the data and continue with the process?

Comment: Ok. 1 more question. Does the queries get processed in a data node which has the data that query requires or just randomly the tasks are spread across the nodes and fetch data?

Comment: Once the data node get that query, it will handle it. No more spread is needed.

Comment: No no. What I am asking is that how the name node will give the query or task to the data node? Will the name node give the query to the data node that has the required data for that task or just randomly will it assign the task to the data nodes who are free?

Comment: The query will be sent to the data node which has the required data, so we can avoid the network transfer(this is called data locality).

Comment: @NancyDrew : There is nothing like "sending" the query to a DN. By virtue of its nature MR framework processes data on the node where it is present. The TaskTracker which is running on the machine where that particular block is present is directed by the JobTracker to start processing based on the availability of CPU slots. In reality you do not send anything(data or query) anywhere. You just start processing at the place where data is present. And this is called as data localization and is inherent to MR.

Comment: But there might be some exceptional cases, like if the nodes where data is present doesn't have any free CPU slots then that block of data will be sent to a nearby node, where free slots are available, and will get processed.

Comment: Ok Tariq. So when the processing is done after the query has been sent to a node which does not have the data, how will it come to the node to get the data? Will the Task tracker take care of that?

Comment: TaskTrackers run continuously on all the nodes. Processing starts only on that node where data is present.